# Why is aliasing inherently non-linear?

Tags: sampling, aliasing, non-linear

E.g. when having 2 signals $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ and transforming each one with adding their spectra, the operation is linear, as the result would be the same as the transformation of $(x + y)(t)$.

Even when looking at the sampling series, each of the infinite elements adds up linearly.

But how is aliasing a non-linear operation and how is it proven mathematically?

Answer (score 6):

I think you mean *"images"*, **not** *"aliases"*.  They become aliases if there is foldover from resampling.

It's because you are not **adding** two signals, $x(t)$ and $\operatorname{III}(t)$, you are multiplying them that these images appear.

$$\begin{align}
x_\text{s}(t) & \triangleq x(t) \cdot \operatorname{III}(t/T)  \\
&= x(t) \cdot \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} T \delta(t-nT) \\
&= T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t) \cdot \delta(t-nT) \\
&= T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x(nT) \cdot \delta(t-nT) \\
&= T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} x[n] \cdot \delta(t-nT) \\
\end{align}$$

where $x[n] \triangleq x(nT)$ and

$$ \operatorname{III}(u) \triangleq \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(u-n) $$

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{III}(t/T) &= \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta\left(\tfrac{t}{T}-n\right) \\
&= \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta\left(\tfrac{t-nT}{T}\right) \\
&= \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} T \delta(t-nT) \\
&= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{j k \frac{2 \pi}{T} t} \\
\end{align}$$

The last line is from doing fourier series.  Now, if you use the shifting property of the Fourier Transform, then the Fourier Transform of $x_\text{s}(t)$ is

$$\begin{align}
X_\text{s}(f) & \triangleq \mathscr{F}\{x_\text{s}(t)\} \\
&= \mathscr{F}\{x(t) \operatorname{III}(t/T) \} \\
&= \mathscr{F}\left\{x(t) \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{j k \frac{2 \pi}{T} t} \right\} \\
&= \mathscr{F}\left\{\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t) \, e^{j k \frac{2 \pi}{T} t} \right\} \\
&= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathscr{F}\left\{ x(t) \, e^{j k \frac{2 \pi}{T} t} \right\} \\
&= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}  X\left(f-\tfrac{k}{T}\right) \\
\end{align}$$

where $ X(f) \triangleq \mathscr{F}\{ x(t) \} $ .

That non-linear process of multiplication generates frequency components than did not previously exist in $x(t)$.  Those new components are simply shifted versions of $X(f)$ and are called *"images"*.

Comment: From the definition of linearity of a system, the process of aliasing under sampling operator seems to be a **linear** one... I suppose the term **aliasing distortion** somewhat creates the misleading understanding that the process is nonlinear. Sampling is a linear (but time varying) operation and aliasing is just a specific case of sampling in which there is spectral overlap. But the time domain exposition is obviously linear: $ y(t) = T\{x(t)\} = (\sum {\delta(t-kT)})x(t) $ OR I'm missing something here. Btw: Aliasing cannot be **inverted** but should all linear transform be (I'm not sure)?

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:**

- Can an LTI system generate components in some frequency $\omega_0$ if the input signal $x(n)$ was such that $X(e^{j\omega_0})=0$?
- Does aliasing do such thing?

The answers to these questions are straightforward and, combined, they answer the original question.

Comment: I know that sampling can be depicted as a succession of linear building blocks, but I fail to remember the source and page. That must be the key, right?

Comment: @Tendero: it is perfectly possible for a linear system to generate new frequencies, if it is time-variant. It is only an LTI system that can't.

Comment: @MBaz Thanks for pointing that out - I've edited the answer.